# Provide a method definition with an abstract version before it?

Tags: java

Is it posible to have:

```
public abstract void someMethod();
...
public void someMethod() {
    // ...
}
```

in the same class? Or does the definition have to be in the child classes?

Comment: Why do you need abstract method when you are defining the method in same class.

Comment: There would be no point doing this in Java as there is no issue with using a method before it is declared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public abstract void someMethod();

public void someMethod() {
   // ...
}
```

In the same class, that is **duplicate method definition**. Not possible. Method are differentiated based on the method signature and not based on modifier like `abstract`.From the official [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html):

*Two of the components of a method declaration comprise the method signature—the method's name and the parameter types.The Java programming language supports overloading methods, and Java can distinguish between methods with different method signatures.*

**Question:**

```
Or does the definition have to be in the child classes?
```

It **can** be a subclass , but it **must** be a **concrete subclass** in the hierarchy.So, the first non abstract subclass should provide implementation for the abstract method. Again, from the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html):

*When an abstract class is subclassed, the subclass usually provides implementations for all of the abstract methods in its parent class. **However, if it does not, the subclass must also be declared abstract.***

Answer (score 1):

You can have the definition in the class, but you can not instantiate that class, only the child class.

Comment: Your example is incomplete because you don't actually have a class there

Comment: That is not possible in the same class. The compiler will give you a duplicate method error

Comment: I see. I thought he meant to have an function in an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force a subclass to implement something, then you should do something like this:

```
public abstract void someMethodHelper();

public final void someMethod()
{
    //Stuff
    someMethodHelper();
}
```

Otherwise, java has all methods as virtual (overrideable) by default.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes the definition has to be in the child class. However, this begs the question: why would you even use an abstract method if you plan to implement it in the parent class? I'm not quite sure what you're tying to do here, but here is a general guideline:

- If the superclass has behavior for the method, just use a normal method (no need for abstraction). The method can still be overrode is subclasses.
- If the superclass not have behavior for the method, make it abstract. All non-abstract subclasses will be forced to override this method with an non-abstract one.
- If you put an abstract method in a class, it is an *abstract class* and objects of that type cannot be created (as they have incomplete behavior).

Hope this helps.